# Sine-Gorldon_equation or Sine-Gordon?

Tags: reference-request

Related to Breather $K=-1$ ; has the [the Wiki Ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine-Gorldon_equation) a spelling mistake?

Comment: It's the [Sine-Gordon equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine-Gordon_equation).

Comment: Thanks, next how to notify this to Wiki?

Comment: @Narasimham: You just edit to correct mistakes that you find. That's the point of Wikipedia – anyone can contribute!